# Wpf Listbox align contest right

Tags: c#, wpf

The code below does not align the text to right. If I do not use Window.Resources (I want to change color of the selected item) code works. Can you help me please?

```
 <Window.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="_ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">            
            <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Border Name="_Border"
                                Padding="2"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            
                            
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="_Border" Property="Background" Value="Gray"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>        
        </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
 <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}" Margin="0,20,0,30" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  MinHeight="200" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  
                  SelectionChanged="myListBox_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="myListBox_MouseDoubleClick" Panel.ZIndex="2" 
                 BorderThickness="0" FontSize="15" Background="{x:Null}" 
                 HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">           
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the `ListBoxItem` ControlTemplate, and your template ignores the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property:

Fix:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
     <Border Name="_Border"
             Padding="2"
             SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
         <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
     </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the style property for your item otherwise the resources window that you create will set it for you.

By doing this I was able to achieve your desire (maybe it is a bit tricky) :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource _ListBoxItemStyle}" Margin="0,20,0,30" 
             VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="800" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  MinHeight="200" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  
             Panel.ZIndex="2"
             BorderThickness="0" FontSize="15" Background="{x:Null}" 
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Right">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="Test"></TextBlock>
        </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```